# Most reliable way to deliver emails from a users email address in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, sendmail, actionmailer, sendgrid

I would like to allow users to send emails which are generated in my rails app from **their** email address .

I know I can just use my servers sendmail, and set the from address to their email address, but there is a high chance the emails will be marked as spam.

Is there a better way to do this? Can I use [sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com/), or [Amazon SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) or make the user input their own SMTP details.

Any suggestions or best practices would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/) support customising the From address. [Heroku](http://heroku.com) provide them as an add-on and they advertise "Complete control over the From: address." on their [add-ons page](http://addons.heroku.com/sendgrid)

Answer (score 7):

This will fail in the face of SPF. SPF is essentially a way for a domain to say "email purporting to be from *this* domain will only be sent from *these* servers", so if you send email from a user at that domain from your server, anyone who does an SPF-check is likely to mark your mail as spam.

Essentially: Don't use the `From` header if the mail's not from the sender, use the `Sender` header instead.

Comment: This is an excellent answer, not sure why it doesn't have more up votes. I've found you can use the `Sender` header in combination with the `From` header; seems to be working great.

Answer (score 5):

Amazon SES is out of the question for this use case: they require an authorization procedure before sending as a certain email address.

Even if you prompted them for SMTP server details, that's going to set off *huge* red flags to any competent users.  Most SMTP servers are properly configured to either require authentication during the SMTP transaction, or require a recent POP3 or IMAP connection, and that means gathering user credentials.  Do you feel like asking your users to trust you with their email password?

Overall, this is actually an astoundingly bad idea, especially considering email authorship proving techniques like [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) / [Sender ID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_ID).  Mails sent this way through non-authorized servers are increasingly likely to get (rightfully) flagged as spam.

Would your use case allow the mails to be "From" your application, but have a "Reply-To" of the user?

Comment: Well, there's always the "Sender" header, but some mail clients display that as "From on behalf of Sender".

Comment: The 'sender' header option is probably a pretty good way to do it, gmail does it that way, on the subject of gmail if sending through a person's SMTP is such an 'astoundingly bad idea' why does gmail give you the option to send emails through an external SMTP gateway in which they store the password and credentials for it???

Comment: Just because it's an astoundingly bad idea doesn't mean it's not something that other people do!

Comment: GMail aims to be an online mail user agent, not simply a web interface for Google's mail services - that's why they and Outlook.exe do it.